# How to rotate set of 3d points using angle axis to rotation matrix?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to rotate a set of 3d points and I am looking at [this function from the kornia library](https://torchgeometry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geometry.conversions.html#kornia.geometry.conversions.angle_axis_to_rotation_matrix). If I try to rotate a point around the z-axis by pi/2, my input(axis angle representation) should be [0, 0, pi/2]. When I use this as input into the function, it returns a 4x4 rotation matrix. However, I don't know how to apply this 4x4 matrix to my data because it is Nx3. What do I do with the output matrix? Thanks!

Comment: Its likely that the function is designed to be used with [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) which is pretty standard since it allows translation to be performed as a linear transform. As suggested by @UsmanAli, keeping only the top-left 3x3 part of the matrix should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at their [source](https://torchgeometry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/kornia/geometry/conversions.html#angle_axis_to_rotation_matrix), they are only updating  3 rows and 3 columns of `torch.eye(4)` tensor. So I think  `rotation_matrix[..., :3, :3]` should provide you with the correct rotation matrix.